# Eclipse cant view class files

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, class, editor

Everytime I try open a class file it gives me this error

```
rg.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor.doSetInput(ClassFileEditor.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2649)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2942)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Though that might not be the correct error log. What I've already done.

1. Download JD-Eclipse from update site
2. Set Class File Editor as default.
3. Adding the class path to build path in project
4. Asking this question on stackoverflow.com

I'm using windows xp.

Please help me

Comment: If i havnt accepted any answers yet it means they didnt help me, though i might be lazy on it, i will still accept answers if they helped me

Comment: Try install a new fresh eclipse install, configure it and import your project in it. Then retry opening your class files.

Comment: Sry i already tried that it always says i have to give a source for the class or sumthing.

Comment: i didnt make the class file its a class file i downloaded from the internet

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse class file editor will not open a .class file that's not part of a java project in the workspace (so you can't use `File > Open File...`)

You can open an enhancement request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=UI

Answer (score 2):

thats all wrong you have to do:
File ==> Open File ==> then go to your workspace an go in the project folder where the file is
but dont go i the bin folder go in the src folder and open the file with .java at the end now you have the file open.

File ==> Open File ==> workspace ==> project folder ==> src folder ==> [Name].java

Answer (score 1):

Editor->File Associations->.java mapping to Java Editor(default)

Comment: For me, it was the `*.class` File Associations

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding the folder that contains the class file(s) as a "Class Folder" under Project Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add Class Folder.

Once I did that, I was able to decompile all the sources properly. Just like the above comment mentioned, it needs to be a part of your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file name select open with options then press java editor options.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the JD-compiler but it did not work for me - I had to use the Class Decompiler Viewer available in the Eclipse Marketplace.

1. Create new project
2. Add relevant source files to project

File -> Import "directory/folder" with *jar files into your project

Assuming that your class files are inside *.jar file.

4. Import Plug-in

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
Search and Install "Enhanced Class Decompiler" plug-in

5. Set Preferences

Window -> Preference -> General -> Editor -> File Associations

Configure both *.class and *.class without source as as Default to "Class Decompiler Viewer"

Apply and Close

6. Now, when I right-click and open a class file there is no error.